# @EnableResourceServer ResourceServerConfiguration Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, cloud-foundry, service-discovery

On Pivotal Cloud Foundry with Spring Services v1.4 if I use Cloud services dependencies version 1.5.0 release and Spring cloud dependencies Dalston SR3, Spring Boot 1.5.6 a rest service with following annotations

```
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCaching
@EnableDiscoveryClient
```

The services failed to start with following error

> 2017-08-21T16:00:28.784-07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-08-21 23:00:28.784 WARN 14 --- [ main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$UserInfoTokenServicesConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userInfoRestTemplateFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoRestTemplateFactory]: Factory method 'userInfoRestTemplateFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: eurekaOAuth2ResourceDetails,configClientOAuth2ResourceDetails

The same code works with Cloud services dependencies version 1.2.1. release and Spring cloud dependencies Brixton SR7 and Spring Boot 1.5.3.

Any ideas what is causing this issue. Thanks.

Comment: You should ask your support contact

Comment: The product team will take a look at this, but as @spencergibb said you should contact Pivotal Support, since this is a commercial product. Support can help look into the problem and keep you updated on progress. https://support.pivotal.io/

Comment: @gamepop I've spent some time putting together a trivial app that contains the dependencies required by the `@Enable` annotation shown above, with the versions you mentioned, and I can't reproduce your error with such a trivial example. Can you share an example app that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Let me try creating a simple version of rest api I have and I will share. Thanks.